# 'module' object has no attribute 'iirnotch'

Tags: python, numpy

'module' object has no attribute 'iirnotch'
i have the latest scipy installed 0.19 and this message appears to however the scipy documentation says that they added this function 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.iirnotch.html

```
from scipy import signal 
fs = 50000 # Sample frequency (Hz)
f0 = 50.0  # Frequency to be removed from signal (Hz)
Q = 30.0  # Quality factor
w0 = f0/(fs/2)  # Normalized Frequency
# Design notch filter
b, a = signal.iirnotch(w0, Q)
```

Comment: did you check in case it is reading the wrong scipy?  scipy.version.version

Answer (score 0):

The version of your scipy should be 0.19.1. If not, try to upgrade scipy and numpy.